# Cannot redirect to specific view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC by trying to convert .NET Web Application to ASP.NET MVC.
I have a controller and login view.
I want to redirect to Default view if user is authenticated.

This is the folder structure:

```
Views
  - Account
  - Home
  - Shared
Default.cshtml
```

This is the Login action in controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         bool authenticated = Security.AuthenticateLANUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
         if (!authenticated)
            {
                Session["authenticated"] = false;
                System.Text.StringBuilder errorMsg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                errorMsg.Append("Invalid Login/Password entered.");
                errorMsg.Append("We were not able to authenticate you in in Active Directory based on the information entered, ");
                errorMsg.Append("but we recorded your attempt for audit purposes.");

                ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMsg.ToString());
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Views/Account/Default.cshtml");
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

The user is authenticated and I'm supposed to be redirected to default view but it does not redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No where in your code are you redirecting. It needs to be `return RedirectToAction("Default", "Account");` assuming you have an `AccountController` with a `Default` method

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be view name, not a view path. So:

```
return View("Default");
```

Also Default view should be defined either in folder corresponding to the current controller (presumably Account) or in Shared folder. The path you are using suggests it is in Account, the structure you have outlined says it is just in Views folder, so I thought it should be mentioned as well.